# How could I map a list including fields that are not found in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-core

It's my first time to use sql in practice, and I've met with such a situation in my .net core project:

I have a table now like this:

| name:string | age:int | ticketType:enum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 20 | 0 |
| Anna | 16 | 1 |
| Tom | 30 | 2 |

And I have a list of name = ["Jack", "George", "William"]

What I need is a table that contains both persons included with certain values and those excluded with default values like:

| name:string | age:string | ticket:string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 20 years | adult |
| George | Not found | Not found |
| William | Not found | Not found |

How could I do this with sql?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join`, but you need a list of the values you care about:

```
select name, t.age, t.tickettype
from (select 'Jack' as name union all
      select 'George' union all
      select 'William'
     ) n left join
     t
     using (name);
```

Note that this represents the "not found" value using `NULL`.  This is the typical method in SQL.  If you want a string, I would suggest that you do that in your application layer, because `int` and `enum` cannot represent an arbitrary string value.

Answer (score 0):

The texdt you have to adapt to your needs

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users
>     (`nameg` varchar(4), `age` int, `ticketType` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO users
>     (`nameg`, `age`, `ticketType`)
> VALUES
>     ('Jack', 20, 0),
>     ('Anna', 16, 1),
>     ('Tom', 30, 2)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.name,IFNULL(CONCAT (`age`, ' years'),'Not Found') age
> , CASE `ticketType`WHEN
>   0 THen  'adult'
> WHEN 1 THEn 'teenager'
> WHEN 2 THEN'elserly'
> ELSE 'NOT Found' END "type"
> FROM (SELECT "Jack" as name UNION SELECT "George" UNION SELECT "William") t1 
> LEFT JOIN users u ON u.nameg = t1.name
> ```
>
> ```
> name    | age       | type     
> :------ | :-------- | :--------
> Jack    | 20 years  | adult    
> George  | Not Found | NOT Found
> William | Not Found | NOT Found
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37a0690e1a3f0bd1d18f16a11f2ea381)*